# How to skip downloading a specific pom in Maven

Tags: maven, dependencies, filtering

I have a maven project consisting of several modules. Initially main project had a `<root>` section, which prevented whole the project to be built due to repository unavailability.

So, I decided to delete parent reference.

Now build process stops at some nested project telling that it is impossible to download a **pom** file. It mentions exactly the parent's pom I've deleted.

There is no any reference to parent project.... Btw, it tries to download pom from 
repository I didn't mention neither in any pom nor in a settings.xml file I explicitly do build with.

So, my questions are: 1 - why maven tries to download pom for a project ( artefact ) which is not mentioned in any of my pom files.
2 - how to tell maven to exclude specific pom file from downloading.
3 - how maven discovers a repository I didn't provide info about.
4 - how to seek&destroy build dependency I wish would not exist, and make build process not to fail because of file unavailability which really must not participate in a build.

P.S.: in my settings.xml I declared !central,*, but had no expected result - maven still tries to ask some other repo for pom I have no  reference in my project to.

Comment: you could have there repostiories mentioned in pom.xml, not in settings.xml. could you show pom.xml?

Comment: by saying exclude specific pom - you mean exclude specific dependency in pom, right?

Comment: Not exacltly. There was an output during a maven build process about pom-file downloading...

Comment: so, what? please be more specific, pom.xml as an example will help

Answer (score 1):

It seems I did manage to figure things out:

1. define all target repositories in settings.xml file
2. define mirror of `!central,!target-repo1,...,!target-repoN`
3. use `grep`tool to find whethere there is a link to that problem maker parent
   project
4. after previous step completed succesfully - edit appropriate pom files to         delete `<parent>` section.

After all of that the result seems to be gotten - there is no any mentioning for misterious pom-file and no any try to download something from not explicitly mentioned repository.

Thank you all very much for your time!